# Using spring WebFlux, how can I get all the RequestHandlerMappings?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reflection, spring-webflux

In the servlet world, I can do something like:

```java
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
    Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> endpoints = context.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class).getHandlerMethods();

    endpoints.forEach((info, method) -> {
      log.info("Info: {}/n method: {}", info, method);
    });
  }
}
```

But, the same does not work in a WebFlux server due to the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` Bean not being registered.

What's the right approach here? Is this even possible?

I could just hold the event for longer, and exhaustively try and find the classes that have a `@RestController` on it.. but in this context I don't know the package name of the potential Controller classes.

Comment: Use the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` from `org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation`.

Comment: Oh boy, I am shocked that it's that easy. If you want, please submit an answer and I'll mark it as correct @SotiriosDelimanolis

I did not notice that the package names were totally different.. so much time spent starting at the same class name in the spring javadoc and source...

Comment: Yeah they reused a lot of the class names for the webflux package. But that's alright, I'm too lazy to provide an answer. You can self answer if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, I've done that now and will confirm it after the waiting period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot reuses a lot of classes. Specifically, there are two `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

For servlet usage, you want to import:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
```

But for reactive usage, it's:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
```

Be careful when making a library that supports both Reactive and Servlet usage - it's easy to import the incorrect class